# Receiving "IndexError: list index out of range" when using count

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, indexing

So I'm trying to cycle through a set of rules using a standard count, but it's returning the error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Here's the code

```
    alphabetList = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
    alphabetList.extend(list(string.ascii_lowercase))
    alphabetDict = {}
    count = 0
    while count <= len(alphabetList):
        item1 = alphabetList[count]
        item2 = item1
        alphabetDict[item1] = item2
        count += 1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: remove the equals sign, and use only the less sign. `while count < len()`

Comment: What, exactly, is this code meant to do? It produces a dict mapping alphabet letters to themselves. Why?

Comment: Lawrence: Thanks, I'll try it. @Daniel I'm creating a caesar cipher for a GCSE assignment. Yeah, fun. The dictionary helps when the letters are being changed. I probably haven't done it in the most efficient way possible, but I'll cross that bridge when the code works! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while count <= len(alphabetList):
```

You're going one past the end of the list here. Change `<=` to `<`.

```
while count < len(alphabetList):
```

---

Alternatively, use `for` instead of `while`.

```
import string

alphabetList = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
alphabetList.extend(list(string.ascii_lowercase))
alphabetDict = {}
for count in range(len(alphabetList)):
    item1 = alphabetList[count]
    item2 = item1
    alphabetDict[item1] = item2
```

---

Alternatively again, iterate directly over the letters without using a `count` value at all.

```
import string

alphabetDict = {}
for item in string.ascii_lowercase:
    alphabetDict[item] = item
```

---

Alternatively again again, construct the dict without a loop by zipping the keys and values together in its initializer.

```
import string
alphabetDict = dict(zip(string.ascii_lowercase, string.ascii_lowercase))
```